# Replace part of filename in URI with htaccess mod_rewrite x-domain solution required

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been trawling the tutorials on htaccess but every example seems to have an absolute URL in the second part of the rewrite. My site delivers across several domains so I need a x-domain solution.

Rule should state the following: Everything that did go to the confirm.php file now goes to confirm/ folder. So...

http://example.com/confirm.php?token=32879 should now go to http://example.com/confirm/?token=32879

AND

http://elpmaxe.com/confirm.php?token=32879 should now go to http://elpmaxe.com/confirm/?token=32879

The code I have come up with is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} confirm.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(confirm\.php)$ confirm/ [L,R=301]
```

But this appends the entire document root path to the end of the URL as follows:

http://example.local/var/www/vhosts/example.co.uk/confirm/?t=CB3Qj&e=578

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(confirm\.php)$ /confirm/ [L,R=301,NC]
```

Make sure to test in a new browser to avoid 301 caching issues.

Comment: Thank you. I had no idea there was such a thing as 301 caching issues in browsers!

Comment: You're welcome. Yes 301 is aggressively cached in all modern browsers, that's why for testing it is better to use `R=302`